# Wait for Api call to complete in Angular 8 error shows undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 if(this.datashare.selectedtableId!=null) {
     console.log( "inside if condition");
     let resp= this.http.get(this.global.apiUrl+"columns/"+this.datashare.selectedtableId);
     resp.subscribe((data)=>this.users=data);
     console.log(this.users);
     this.count=this.users.length;
  }
```

when I console the users it shows all the data from API in my console like that `(console.log(data))` But in my component, I try to get the data at the starting of the page by calling the service and assign it to a local variable it is giving undefined.

Comment: In order to make it clear, you should check the code (the first line is not formatted for example) and then include the code on which you're receiving the undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the value for variable inside of the `subscribe`.

Because when ever you subscribe to an `Observable` current thread won't stop till the execution of it, simply it moves to the next line until it gets response from subscription.

Try to make below changes

```
...

resp.subscribe((data)=>{
    this.users = data;
    console.log(this.users);       //   --> you can find here response data 
    this.count = this.users.length;
});

console.log(this.users);           //  --> will give you undefined 
...
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks, a lot sir for helping. ill appreciate that.